# Getting and reading unmanaged C++ pointer in .Net

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I’m having an issue getting the correct data back from a C++ API that was P/Invoke in C#.
The C++ function is set up to take a pointer to store the data requested, along with size and what exact parameter you want to retrieve. There is obviously something wrong with my setup and I’m looking for suggestions.
Thank you!

C++ Proto:

```
DECL_FOOAPIDLL DWORD WINAPI FOO_GetVal(
VOID *Val,  //pointer to memory where the data will be stored by the function
DWORD Len,  //length of Val in bytes
DWORD Id    //identification number of the parameter
);
```

C# P/Invoke signature:

```
[DllImport(FOO_API, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static public extern uint FOO_GetVal(IntPtr val, uint len, uint id);
```

my C# code to get information on setting:

```
IntPtr Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
uint hr = FOOWrapper.FOO_GetVal(Ptr, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(Ptr), FOOWrapper.CMD_RUNNING);
int result = Marshal.ReadInt32(Ptr);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Ptr);
```

So the big question is am i reading the returned pointer correctly via Marshal.ReadInt32()?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing before I can help you is that you need to make the calling conventions match.  They currently do not.

Comment: According to MSDN DWORD is equivalent to uint in C#...the first is obviously a pointer… I have several other C++ prototypes that perform other operation set up in a similar manor and they all work fine…

Comment: @Dan - Do you know what I mean by making sure the calling convention of your C# code matches your C++ code?

Comment: [DllImport(FOO_API, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with the pinvoke declaration.  The way you use it isn't correct, you are reserving space for an IntPtr but are reading an int.  The proper code ought to be:

```
uint len = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int));
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
uint hr = FOOWrapper.FOO_GetVal(ptr, len, FOOWrapper.CMD_RUNNING);
if (hr != 0) throw new COMException("FOO_GetVal failed", hr);
int result = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

The addition is important, you certainly don't want to ignore an error return code.  If it is actually an error code, your use of "hr" suggest it does but the declaration suggest it isn't.  If it is the size of the actual data then change it to:

```
uint actual = FOOWrapper.FOO_GetVal(ptr, len, FOOWrapper.CMD_RUNNING);
if (actual != len) throw new Exception("Improper data size");
```

This furthermore assumes that the parameter you are asking for is actually an int.  Impossible to say, but a "CMD_RUNNING" sounds more like a bool, one byte in C++.

Just debug this to find out what the problem might be.  Tick the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" checkbox in Project + Properties, Debug tab.  And set a breakpoint on the FOO_GetVal() function in your native code.

Comment: Yes,
Thanks for clearing up that pointer declaration. I’m actually working with a C++ API, I have no access to the source, just the header file. The last parameter isn’t what it seems… I just made that up for example… It really takes an id that references a setting, the state of the setting will be stored in the allocated pointer.
Thank you

Comment: Oh,
I named the return value hr because the function only returns SUCCESS or FAIL… I kept the data type uint simply for consistency.